# Problem question about male characters: Can we save it by editing?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Regarding this question:

- **[Question to all men about men and their feelings and ability to talk about them! (as research for my novel)](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/how-should-i-have-my-male-character-express-strong-feelings?noredirect=1)**

It's pretty general, but I think there's a solid question in there about how to realistically write male characters. We should have placed it when it was asked in December but we missed it.

How can we edit this to be a more appropriate question for the site? Monica's edited the title for now, and that helps, but I think we need to edit the text as well.

Bonus: How do we do this without invalidating the answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncharacteristically, I'm of the opinion that this is fairly close to a fine question. :)

The title change was absolutely necessary; we don't do survey questions, and this shouldn't be answered as a survey question. But in most of its other details, it's in precisely what I see as the most pragmatic, answerable type of Stack Exchange question:
I tried to do X; I got stuck against problem Y; how do I solve this.

Certainly the question is making very simplistic assumptions and broad generalizations; but, well, that's what OP's question *is*.

I think the question could be improved, for this focus. The "Wouldn't you--" survey-style questions could be converted to something more on the lines of "I think a man would do , my friend says they never would".
And the ending - "Make me understand the mind of a man!" is indeed broad and unanswerable. But tweak the last bit to "I thought love, sadness and anger are universal feelings that everyone has regardless of their gender; but how do I square that in my writing with the sense that men conceal their feelings entirely, or don't feel that much to begin with?", and you have an extremely answerable question.

I've just made an edit along these lines, and you can tell me if it appeals.

Comment: Great edit, I reopened the question and left a note for the OP to confirm that we didn't overdo it.

Answer (score 1):

I just re-edited and voted to reopen the question after a heroic edit by someone. I didn't address the issues mentioned here. @Standback You might have another go at editing the question. If nothing else, the number of views and responses indicate that it has some resonance with the audience of Writers SE.

Comment: Nice wrinkle; it might go a bit beyond the OP's intent, but let's see what they say (I left a note).

Comment: I feel like there should be a statute of limitations for removals. IF an interval elapses AND a question gets a certain amount of activity IT should receive immunity from being closed.

Comment: there's a meta question about this, if I remember correctly. Will look for it later when I'm not on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I would conclude the question with: Do men and women express strong feelings in different ways and different circumstances? When and how might this be the case?"

This is a matter of fact variation that explores the different "mechanics" of men and women's feelings.